# Why do some questions show up as asked by Community?

Tags: support

So I was browsing the top lists today, and noticed a few have Community (diamond) as the asker:

[image]

However, in the question, it says the actual person's name:

[image]

Any idea why it does this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On listings of posts, the username you see is the user who made the latest change to the question or any answers - be that answering the question, editing it, or asking it. Community didn't *ask* the question, it just changed it in some way.

There are two cases where the community user would show up here:

- Suggested edits from anonymous users show up as being from Community
- Community randomly "bumps" questions that have no answers

Comment: Community bumps two questions per hour on the hour. It looks like this is the case here, also given the time this question was asked.